# ASP.NET Configuration tool fails in MVC application

Tags: asp.net

Whenever I try to use ASP.NET Configuration tool in my MVC application it shows error in Security tab. The error is:

```
There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid
server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused 
by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be 
redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Could not load type
'LL.MvcApplication'.
```

Please note that `LL` is my application name. ASP.NET Configuration tool works fine in non MVC web application.

What can be the issue and how can I use ASP.NET authentication in my MVC application?

I have tried both in VS 2008 and VS 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application name in web.config was appearing as "/" by default and when I set a proper name ("/LL") the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is the connection string in your web.config. If you have none (and are trying to automagically create the membershipt data?) consider using the sql script to create the database, attaching it, and then altering the connection string. In summary:

1. Make sure the database is created or create it
2. Make sure the database is attached to the server
3. Make sure the connection string to the database is correct

Once you do this, you should be past the problem. Have not dinked with this much in MVC, but the same problem happens in web forms, esp. if you are not using SQL Express (or access?) or have named it other than default.